# Media/search Endpoint returns only posts with location

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am using the media/search endpoint API for while which returns all posts in the defined geo boundary however around mid August the API only returns posts that users manually assigned venue by checking in. Basically, a large portion of posts are missing since usually users don't check in at venues. I need to import all posts based on the lat and long not only the posts that have venues like "central park".
Can anyone help me on this issue?

[Example one](https://instagram.com/p/8TihJ_ErV8/):
(this example shows that using the same endpoint I can get only docs that user manually assigned location. In this example, user added "Hyatt Regency Orange County" for the post.).

[Example two](https://instagram.com/p/6LFGypwiP8/):
(example two shows that before mid August using the same API I could get all posts even without any venue assigned using just lat,long. If you open the post there is no assigned location.).

And here is the example query:

//api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=34.043835&lng=-118.267211&max_timestamp=1409484959&min_timestamp=1409454959&distance=100

Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they've removed the ability for their App to auto-tag photos with geolocation information that it pulls from the phone.

I just did some testing by posting some photos. I have given Instagram full access to my location services and then posted 2 pictures. One tagged with a location, the other not tagged with a location. When I request that media back from Instagram I get

```
    "location": {
        "latitude": 51.039733624,
        "name": "Galaxie Diner",
        "longitude": -114.089168127,
        "id": 2488384
    },
```

for the tagged picture and

```
    "location": null,
```

for the untagged picture.

My guess is that its part of a corporate strategy to drive usage of the location tagging feature since those locations are usually associated with Facebook location pages. Either that or they've disabled it out of privacy concerns.

Comment: Tony: yes, you are right. They either changed their privacy policy or corporate strategy. That's a huge change for the SaaS platforms. Our Instagram importer lost about 60% of data from the time they changed it. We already have location table in our Mysql using Foursquare however we need to have post lat,long which Instagram removed from the API in case user didn't put any location.